# Script PHP incremento

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso criar um script em PHP que toda vez que ele fosse executado ele iria incrementar e imprimir esse numero. Exemplo: Na primeira execução ele mostra o numero 1. Na segunda vez o numero 2. Na terceira vez o numero 3. Porém na Quarta vez ele teria que retornar para o numero 1.

Comment: Era isso mesmo agora irei implementar no meu projeto. Muito obrigado.

Comment: A melhor forma de agradecer é aceitando a resposta que mais te ajudou ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível mas você tera que salvar o número em algum lugar(banco de dados ou um arquivo mesmo)

Exemplo salvando o número em um arquivo:

```
// script.php
$numero = file_get_contents('arquivo_salva_numero');
if (!empty($numero) && $numero < 3) {
    $numero++;
} else {
    $numero = 1;
}
echo $numero;
file_put_contents('arquivo_salva_numero', $numero);
```

toda vez que o você executar "php script.php" ele vai ler o arquivo "arquivo_salva_numero", em seguida incrementa e imprimi o número e salva o novo número no arquivo novamente.
Isso seria uma forma de implementar, mas como já mencionaram depende do que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 0):

**Salvando em um arquivo de texto**

> Verifique se o arquivo existe para evitar um `PHP Warning:...`

```
$arquivo="contaatetres.txt";
//verifica se o arquivo existe
if (file_exists($arquivo)) {

   //lê o conteúdo do arquivo
   $numero=file_get_contents($arquivo);

      if($numero<3){
          $numero++;
      }else{
          $numero=1;
      }
      
}else{
    $numero=1;
}

//Se o arquivo não existir é criado. Se existir é sobrescrito.
file_put_contents("contaatetres.txt", $numero);  


echo "O numero é $numero";
```